# Can't we Create SQL server Function with parameters that passed by reference "Output"?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, user-defined-functions

SQL SERVER avoid us to pass paramter as output "pass by reference" in SQL Function
it just allows us to do so in procedures
is there any way to do that in functions ?

if Not, please can anyone help me  to assign value in Select statement

like this example:

```
Declare @X as float
set @X 
select  column1, column2,  @X = @X+ column1+column2 FROM someView
```

Comment: How do you order that table ?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to achieve here. You want to have a resultset with a calculated column? You want to return a value?

Comment: LeftyX, what he want is to have the sum of previous column in each row in select result. So if the rows value are, (1,2,3) the output should be (1,3,6).

Comment: @Vash: thanks for his clarification ;-) Well, I would have done what you have done, then!

Comment: Is this more correctly "How can I get a running total in SQL Server"?

Comment: yes Vash your right,  but i've tried a nested select as you show me, but it takes a lot of time when data is more than 5000 rows

Comment: @Khaleel Hmoz: Again, is this more correctly "How can I get a running total in SQL Server"?

Answer (score 1):

To produce such result you can try this solution:

```
SELECT s1.column1, s1.column2, sum(s1.column1 + s1.columns2) as res 
FROM  someView s1 cross join someView s2 
WHERE s1.[OrderColum] <= s1.[OrderColum]
GROUP BY s1.column1, s1.columns2
```

but if you don't have some order column you can try this solution

```
WITH someViewWithOrder AS
(
    SELECT column1,column2,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS row_id
        FROM someView
) 
SELECT s1.column1, s1.column2, sum(s1.column1 + s1.columns2) as res
    FROM someViewWithOrder s1
        INNER JOIN someViewWithOrder s2 ON s1.row_id >= b.row_id
GROUP BY s1.column1, s1.columns2;
```

Comment: Your 2nd solution will give rubbish results: it's still a random order. You can't invent an order with SELECT 1. And you can't have an ON clause with CROSS JOIN.

Comment: Thank you Vash , Your first Select is work and im using it, but i found that it takes !n  times which means a lot of time as long as your data is huge... so using for each will be better solution ,  But if i found a way to assign a variable inside a retrieval select statement that would be awesome

Comment: @gbn, yep that on was unfortunate, but i'm not inventing order only the sequence values, so that statement is correct and will not give rubbish results, it can be used there column1 instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the result like this

```
Declare @X as float

select @X = sum(column1 + column2) 
FROM someView
```

to calculate a running total [this approach](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2009/07/28/SQL-Server-2005-Fast-Running-Totals.aspx) works (fast)

Comment: you it works but you can't select another columns because you can't use assigning select with retrieval data select

Comment: as @gbn mentioned, is what you really want a "running total"?

Comment: well yes i need running total, but i've tried the way that Vash showed it takes  (N) factorial Times  , like when Data is more 5000 rows it takes  more than one minute to calculate because it calculate !n times for each row

Comment: So i just need to know if there is a way to assign variable within a retrieval select statement which will help alot... but if we couldn't Ill use for each Statment wich will just take (N) Times

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for a recursive CTE:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT
    Column1,
    Column2,
    rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
  FROM someView
),
RecCTE AS (
  SELECT
    Column1,
    Column2,
    Total = Column1 + Column2
  FROM CTE
  WHERE rownum = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    c.Column1,
    c.Column2,
    Total = r.Total + c.Column1 + c.Column2
  FROM CTE c
    INNER JOIN RecCTE ON c.rownum = r.rownum + 1
)
SELECT *
FROM RecCTE
```